# wrong results for clock() on 64 bit

Tags: macos, 64-bit, clock

I've got a simple benchmarking function using the C `clock()` function.

```
start[timerId]=clock();
clock_t end;
float dif_sec;
end=clock();
dif_sec=((float)end-start[timerId])/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("%s: %f seconds\n", msg, dif_sec);
```

It's running fine in 32 bits on Mac OS X, but when I compile in 64 bits, the results are all wrong. Why?!

Comment: Please explain what you expect to happen, and what does, so that we'd have any hope of answering your question.

Comment: Here is the output of 2 consecutive calls on the same machine, 1st in 32 bits, and then in 64 bits. It roughly takes the same time, despite what is being printf-ed.

macbook:Release alexis$ ./test l boat.ppm output.ppm 
analyze: 0.030000 seconds
process: 1.000000 seconds
render: 0.080000 seconds

macbook:Release alexis$ ./test l boat.ppm output.ppm 
analyze: 207.559998 seconds
process: 11289.139648 seconds
render: 648.200012 seconds


The issue is that clock() returns much larger integer in 64 bits, whereas CLOCKS_PER_SEC is still 100. Ideas?

Comment: You do realize that `clock()` is _processor time_ and not _wall clock time_ right?  How are you compiling in 32 vs 64 bit mode?  And, finally, `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is usually defined as 1,000,000 at least that is what it is on my MacBook Pro - look at the _STANDARDS_ section of the clock(3) manpage.

Comment: Oh... one more thing... try `getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &r0);` and compare `r0.ru_utime` with what you are seeing. It should come pretty close to matching.

Comment: I'm compiling both 32 and 64 bits with Intel compiler (i386, x86_64), and CLOCKS_PER_SEC is 100 on my Macbook.

Comment: If the Intel compiler says CLOCKS_PER_SEC is 100 and the MacOS X compiler says it is 1000000, then there is a problem.  It could be that the Intel compiler is not using the regular C library and has its own version of the clock() function - or it could be a simple bug.

Comment: Also, vectorizer, the comments you've placed would probably be better off in the question (you can edit it - or should be able to do so). And you should also review the answers you've been offered to other questions - and accept some.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I got from a pure C version of your code (MacOS X 10.5.8 - Leopard; MacBook Pro):

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    clock_t end   = clock();
    float dif_sec = ((float)end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%s: %f seconds\n", "difference", dif_sec);
    printf("%s: %d\n", "CLOCKS_PER_SEC", CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return(0);
}
```

This is how I compiled it, and ran it, and the results I got:

```
Osiris JL: gcc -m32 -o xxx-32 xxx.c
Osiris JL: gcc -m64 -o xxx-64 xxx.c
Osiris JL: ./xxx-32
difference: 0.000006 seconds
CLOCKS_PER_SEC: 1000000
Osiris JL: ./xxx-64
difference: 0.000009 seconds
CLOCKS_PER_SEC: 1000000 
Osiris JL: ./xxx-64
difference: 0.000003 seconds
CLOCKS_PER_SEC: 1000000
Osiris JL: ./xxx-32
difference: 0.000003 seconds
CLOCKS_PER_SEC: 1000000
Osiris JL:
```

Looks sort of OK - rather fast, perhaps, but that's OK; it is a nice new machine, and it doesn't take long to make two system calls in a row.

Comment: clock_t start = clock();
    sleep (1);
    clock_t end   = clock(); this gives me 0.000026 secs on my machine where CPS value is printed 1000000

Comment: See the POSIX man page for [`clock()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock.html), where it says '_The `clock()` function shall return the implementation's best approximation to the processor time used by the process since the beginning of an implementation-defined era related only to the process invocation._'  When a process sleeps, it does not use CPU time.